# Trim in delphi xe7

Tags: string, delphi, trim, delphi-xe7

I am using the `trim` function to a string but as I see it is not working well. I have 
text, `text_trim: string` and I do :

```
text := memo1.text;
text_trim := text.Trim;
```

But it is not working. It just copies the string.

If I write for example in the memo: "Hello how are you?" text content is this(Hello how are you?) and text_trim has also the same content. I want to trim white spaces in a text.

Answer (score 4):

`Trim` removes leading and trailing space. It does not remove internal space. For example you could use `StringReplace` for that.

```
NewStr := OldStr.Replace(' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

This just replaces the space character. If you want to replace all whitespace then you need something a little more advanced. Probably a regex would be the simplest way to achieve that.